Remove the right margin of a flex-wrapped item
As shown in the below picture, there is a gap between the two flex item when the text in the first item is wrapped. Is there a way to remove this gap? Thank you.

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.child-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.color-block {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 0.5rem;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="child-container">
    <div>← Previous Article:</div>
    <div>A very long article title. A very long article title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="color-block"> </div>
</div>

Also on Jsfiddle Demo
Tried flex-basis, margin right, 0 shrink but nothing works

what is the expected result?

It's not reproducing for me.

Resize the window, so that the content wraps @LajosArpad
